# How to set Angular Clarity Design 4.0 input width to 100%?

Tags: css, angular, vmware-clarity

For older versions, I have no difficulty overriding the default CSS behaviour of Clarity Design form controls to use 100% of the parent width.

With the 4.0 version, I can't even set `style="width: 100%"` on Chrome Inspector for `clr-input-container` and all child elements (`clr-control-container`, `clr-input-wrapper`, `input`).

Anyone have luck trying to make the input elements of Clarity Design 4.0 fit 100% width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clr-*` class to apply styling on input. For example,

```
.clr-input,
.clr-input-wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.clr-control-container, 
.clr-input-wrapper.clr-input {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v2-auvess).

Comment: Hello, your answer works good if I'm using only CSS components. 

Take a look [at this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v2-fknzkd?file=src/app/app.component.html) 

It's the same Stackblitz that you sent to me but with Clarity Angular Input Component. 

Any tips to make the 100% width with the Angular input component?

Comment: @IbrahimNetto take a look at this one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v2-auvess. Updated answer, let me know if you could accept it.